# Only change content using Gatsby Link

Tags: gatsby

I'm using GatsbyJS to build a site but was expecting the Router to behave slightly differently in that it would act more like the routers in SPAs and only change the content that was changed rather than full page re-loads.

For example if I have:

```
<Link to="/next-page/">Go to Next Page</Link>
```

This loads the entire next page and re-renders everything. Including the headers, layout, etc.

How can I make it so that ONLY the content is changed?

I noticed that on the official Gatsby website this behaviour is the case, but in practice it seems to load and re-render the entire next page. Do you need to use a different component?

For example if I have these three files:

layout.js

```
<div>
   <header>Header</header>
   <main>{children}</main>
</div>
```

index.js

```
<Layout>
  <Link to="/next-page/">Go to Next Page</Link>
</Layout>
```

next-page.js

```
<Layout>
  <Link to="/">Go to First Page</Link>
</Layout>
```

I'm expecting that the header content should not be re-loaded and rendered on the click of the next link. So if I changed the text via the Web Inspector for the header, I'd expect this text to not change as only part of the web page should be getting updated. You can test this on the Gatsby website by editing any part of the header HTML and then navigating around and see that the header HTML is never re-rendered... but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This became the default behaviour in Gatsby v2, but I find the same thing: it’s very common to want the global layout to persist. You can add that functionality back with the official [gatsby-plugin-layout](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-layout/) plugin.

Run the following command:

```sh
npm install --save gatsby-plugin-layout
```

Add the plugin to your `gatsby-config.js` plugins array:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [

    // Etc…

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-layout`,
      options: {
        component: require.resolve(`./relative/path/to/layout/component`),
      },
    },

    // Etc…

  ],
}
```

…with the path to your layout component.

More background:

- [Why would you want to reimplement the V1 layout behavior?](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-layout/#why-would-you-want-to-reimplement-the-v1-layout-behavior)
- [How to prevent layout components from unmounting](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/layout-components/#how-to-prevent-layout-components-from-unmounting)

Answer (score -1):

These can be done with:

```
const layout = (props) => {
    return (
      <Header />
      <Content
         {...props}
      />
      <Footer />
    )
}
```

`Header.js`

```
const header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
     <p>some text</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`Content.js`

```
const content = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{ props.children } </div>
  )
}
```

`Footer.js`

```
const footer = () => {
  return (
    <div>
     <p> some footer </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`Header, Content, Footer` are separate components.

You will use then layout template for the whole page and you will have the same header and footer on all sites.

Comment: That’s not what I’m asking. I already have the same header on each page. The question was how do you make the Link component load the next page into the content only like how the Gatsby site does, instead of doing a full page reload or having to use custom Ajax.

Comment: You can look here:
https://gatsby-starter-blog-demo.netlify.app/

Github code: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/starters/blog

Comment: That’s not loading in the content using Ajax